# How to define the encoding of a retrieved html page (xpath)

Tags: php, html, xpath, character-encoding, domdocument

When retrieving a webpage (which is not my own). XPath returns weird characters. When using

```
iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1",$xpath_results->item(0)->nodeValue)
```

It's all good. However, it's not very neat to have to do this every time. The returned html looks like this:

> WeekÂ 26Â HuiswerkklasÂ heleÂ week aanvangÂ 13.30Â uur Dinsdag 26 juni
>   Vergadering feestcommissie 10.00 uur Lok.9

How can I set the correct encoding when loading the webpage instead of doing it every time when exporting.

When looking to similar questions, I've tried the following:

```
$uitval_document->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.file_get_contents(BASE_URL_uitval68.$value->getAttribute('href')));
```

Which did not work of course, because it's HTML and not XML i'm retrieving. In HTML the encoding would go in the head tag. So it would be possible to load the HTML add it to the headtag, and reload it with the correct encoding. But that's not very efficient and quite hackish. Do you guys know a better solution?

Comment: You can get the doc out originally and search for the encoding definition inside of the head using http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php and if its not there create a new node in that location and then reload it with http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php where you just put the string output of the previus object.

Comment: @Sammaye That's exactly what i said in the last paragraph, and it's also described there why I don't really like it.

Comment: Well PHP has no way to 'guess' the encoding if you don't supply it. You either use iconv or http://php.net/manual/fr/function.utf8-encode.php. If the page itself has an encoding DOMDocument *should (though can't even bet on that)* take it but if no encoding is set then you are the one whos gonna have to do the leg work.

Comment: @Sammaye So there is no way to let domdocument know the encoding of the page is UTF8 when loading it? Well except for the method described above.

Comment: There is one more thing you can try as a last ditch. IN the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) youll notice a public var in the class named: $encoding. If you set this to "utf-8" it might allow you to set its encoding upon creation, I have never tried this.

Comment: XPath is just a *query* language for XML documents -- as such it *doesn't alter* the source XML document in any way -- including its encoding.